# Start and stop reloading a page with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to reload a page every X amount of seconds with Javascript, I need to be able to hit a button to stop it and start it though

So when you go to the page it will just start refreshing every 5 seconds, then you can hit a stop button.  Once stopped you can hit a start button to get it going again.

I am not sure how I can do this, can someone help, so far all I got is this..

```
<script>

function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}
timedRefresh(5000);

</script>
```

Just need a way to stop it and start it up again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this on your page,

```
var timer = function() {
  window.location.reload(true);
};
var timeout = setTimeout(timer, 5000);
```

When stopped,

```
clearTimeout(timeout);
```

When started,

```
setTimeout(timer, 5000);
```

**Update**: updated after the poster updated the question.

Comment: Hi, is clearTimeout and setTimeout some kind of built in JS function?

Comment: Always amused by the use of a function expression where a declaration will do. It seems like a pointless use of extra characters.

Comment: Sometimes it's just a few more words to express functions are first-class citizens in the JavaScript world. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var rld = setTimeout(window.location.reload, 5000);
```

To cancel it when user presses stop button:

```
clearTimeout(rld);
```